# In HTML5, different browsers support different formats of video

Tags: html, video

Does it mean that I need videos of multiple formats so that it can be played on different browsers by adding multiple sources to the tag?

Comment: Yes. Some formats are supported on more browsers than others. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5_Media) for more information

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html explains this quite well.

Comment: @m2o - the URL for diveintohtml5 has been changed (mirrored) to http://diveintohtml5.ep.io

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes unfortunately you do... I think the browser just selects the right forward from what you have available on your server.

check out this neat tutorial on html5 video integration: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you stay away from W3Schools as sadly it's full of errors and mistakes. [Adding video to your website with HTML5](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2010/05/18/adding-video-to-your-website-with-html5/).

Answer (score 1):

this page has a rather exhaustive discussion about the various formats of video supported by various browsers http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html